# Sorting in RxJava: Is there a better way to do it?

Tags: rx-java

I need to return a `Observable<CostCenter>` emitting centers sorted by `name`

```
  public Observable<CostCenter> getCostCenters() {
        return dao.getCostCenters().toSortedList(new Func2<CostCenter, CostCenter, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(CostCenter costCenter, CostCenter costCenter2) {
                return costCenter.getName().compareTo(costCenter2.getName());
            }
        }).flatMap(new Func1<List<CostCenter>, Observable<CostCenter>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<CostCenter> call(List<CostCenter> costCenters) {
                return Observable.from(costCenters);
            }
        });
    }
```

`dao.getCostCenters()` returns `Observable<CostCenter>`. Is there any operator to convert a `Observable<List<T>>` to `Observable<T>` without using `flatMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `observable.sorted(comparator)` which was introduced in rxjava 1.1.9.

Comment: Thanks! I was using version 1.1.1.